# How to create directories and move specific files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a large number of files named like this: `A1234-20190101-A`. Their suffix will be one of the following: `-O`, `-PM`, `-M`, `-P`, `-A`, `-R`. They are a mixture of file types e.g. *.wav*, *.mp3*, *.jpg*, etc.

I need to create a structure with a parent directory that contains six subfolders: `1-Original`, `2-Preservation Master`, `3-Mezzanine`, `4-Presentation`, `5-Access`, `6-Reference`. The first two parts of the filename creates the name of the parent directory (the above file should create a directory named: `A1234-20190101`). The filename suffix determines what subdirectories the files are moved into (`O` for *Original*, `PM` for *Preservation Master*, etc.).

```
import os
import shutil

path = "/Volumes/ADATA UFD/For script/Files"
file_names = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file))]
sub_folders = ['1-Original','2-PreservationMaster','3-Mezzanine','4-Presentation','5-Access','6-Reference']
file_map = {'O':'1-Original','P':'2-PreservationMaster','M':'3-Mezzanine','T':'4-Presentation','A':'5-Access','R':'6-Reference'}

parent_folders = set(file_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0] for file_name in file_names)

for folder in parent_folders:
    folder_path = os.path.join(path, folder)

    try:
        os.mkdir(folder_path)
    except:
        print('folder already exist:', folder_path)

    for folders in sub_folders:
        try:
            folders_path = os.path.join(folder_path, folders)
            os.mkdir(folders_path)
        except:
            print('folder already exists:', folders_path)

for file_name in file_names:
    parent_folder = file_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[19]
    print(ext)
    dest = os.path.join(path, parent_folder, file_map[ext], file_name)
    src = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    try:
        shutil.move(src, dest)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/ADATA UFD/For script/MoveFilesToPreservationBundleTest3.py", line 30, in 
    dest = os.path.join(path, parent_folder, file_map[ext], file_name)
builtins.KeyError: ()

Running the code currently creates named directories which contain the six subdirectories. I'm struggling with moving the files into the specific subdirectories though.

Example of complete directories:

> A1234-20190101
>   --|1-Original
>   --|2-PreservationMaster
>   -----|A1234-20190101-PM.wav
>   --|3-Mezzanine
>   --|4-Presentation
>   --|5-Access
>   -----|A1234-20190101-A.mp3
>   -----|A1234-20190101-A.jpg
>   --|6-Reference

Comment: when you use `os.path.join()`` then you have to assign result to variable `fullpath = os.path.join(...)` or use it directly in other function `s.mkdir( os.path.join(...) )` But you don't do this.

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.